# Syntax highlighting randomly disappears during file saving

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using vim to edit some python files and recently it occurs sporadically that the syntax highlighting disappears after I save the buffer inside vim. I tried to reset `syntax on` and `set filetype=python` but to no avail. I have no clue of what causes this problem at all, so right now I have minimal diagnostic info. But has anyone encountered this before, or where could things break down?

Comment: Can you post your vimrc?

Comment: @mdkess It's fairly long, I just upload it to pastebin http://pastebin.com/dggSfKkX

Comment: @Kevin plugins are ack.vim,          LaTeX-Box,             vim-align,             vimroom,          Latex-Text-Formatter,  vim-colors-solarized,  vim-surround,
ctrlp.vim,        nerdtree,              vim-indexed-search,
gundo.vim,        tComment,              vim-markdown,
jpythonfold.vim,  toggle_words.vim,      vim-powerline,

Comment: Does it help doing `:e`? I had some problem with mixed up syntax once and it wasn't enough with setting `filetype`.

Comment: @244an Interesting. `:e` indeed recovers the highlighting - but is there a way to avoid this problem in the beginning? and what do you mean by "mixed syntax" (mine is pure python code)?

Comment: I too faced the same issue, specifically when I was tabbing for completion (llvm). Accepted answer fixed it. Thanks to both, questioner and answerer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a solution, but it's hard to write/read in the comments.

I meant that I was messing around with syntax/highlighting when I start to fix my own `.vimrc`, thats why I noticed it.
`syntax on` / `syntax enable` is only preparing for file load stuff (adding a lot of `au` to `BufNewFile / BufRead`). So if some plugin is messing with syntax/highlight settings when writing the file, the file must be loaded again for all "magic" to happen, it's not enough with setting `filetype`. Do `:au BufRead` and you will see all autocommands added when starting syntax. But the file must be loaded then to get all settigs.
See this:> [`syntax-loading`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax-loading)

If you don't want to reload the file, try `syntax enable`, I think that is different to `syntax on`.
Or try also doing `:doautocmd filetypedetect BufRead %`, see > [`autocmd-execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-execute)

I don't know what is causing the problem, can it be you? If you added some autocommands, or doing own colors/syntax?
Otherwise, until you get a solution, you can perhaps try to add `autocmd BufWritePost * <with the commands above that works>` at the end of your `.vimrc`, use `augroup` in that case.

Here is an example:

```
augroup myResetSyntax
  au!
  autocmd BufWritePost * syntax enable | doautocmd filetypedetect BufRead "%"
augroup END
```

Comment: One thing I noticed during `strace -f vim test-file.type 2>/tmp/vim-strace.out` is that the trace file shows the missing 3 VIM files during `source $MYVIMRC`.  Ordering of file processing during initial Vim session is: 

    /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax,
    /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin.vim,
    $HOME/.vim/ftplugin,
    
Argh!!!  Can't format lines in comments.  In short, the load sequence of `:scriptnames` during initial startup is NOT the same as the load sequence of `:scriptnames` during `:source $MYVIMRC`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also restore the syntax by reloading the buffer simply by:

```
:e
```

Answer (score 2):

Now after a while I realize the screwy highlighting is caused by folding rather than than any mysterious forces associated with file saving, so a simple fix* would be to put the following in my vimrc

```
noremap <F9> <Esc>:syntax sync fromstart<CR>
inoremap <F9> <C-o>:syntax sync fromstart<CR>
```

and press F9 whenever something screwy happens.

- Solution discovered from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

You can first save file with

```
:w
```

And afterwards refresh the buffer with

```
:e
```