# Changing colorschemes in vim disables syntax highlighting for html

Tags: html, vim

So yeah, the question is in the title. The situation is that, imaging one vim window split into one half of html and the other half css. When I change the colorscheme from say Badwolf to molokai, the syntax coloring on the html disappears. Any reasons why?

When I change the colorscheme it seems that only html filetypes is affected (as css syntax highlighting is still present), and most colorschemes don't highlight the syntax. examples include molokai, monokai, etc with exceptions being badwolf and gruvbox.

Do you guys think this is a bug or is there something wrong with my _vimrc? Really don't wanna go through 100+ lines of code all neatly folded last night :(

Comment: This doesn't happen in my environment, so I believe it's either i) something wrong in your vimrc or ii) some plugin you've installed is misbehaving. Make a backup of your vimrc (or use git etc.), and try a binary search. That'll save you a lot of work tracing the cause.

Comment: I reinstalled vim even and with a clean vimrc, yet it still doesnt work. even on a random html page i downloaded off the internet. sigh what to do... soz my ocd is kreepin

keep in mind, im using gvim on windows 7 :p

Comment: That's sad.. Can you add the output of `:verb set filetype` and `:verb set syntax` in the affected html buffer (after the highlighting disabled)? Meanwhile, you might have some luck trying the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786011) (Change `BufWritePost` to `ColorScheme`).